# Windows doesn't like resized FAT filesystem

Tags: windows, gparted, fat

I resized a FAT filesystem.  Then the filesystem  stopped working as a Windows 10 Recovery Drive.  ("This may be due to a recent change in your hardware or software...").  And a running Windows is unable to open the filesystem, when it could before.

Resize tool: gparted-0.27.0-1.fc25.x86_64 (Fedora 25)

The resize was performed on a disk image file, copied from a USB drive as a backup.  `gparted` was run on a loop device created from the image file using `losetup -f -P`. (Or later, Gnome Disks and "Attach Disk Image" from the... whatever you call the app-specific menu, in the top bar of gnome shell).

Comment: On SuperUser: [gParted: FAT32 formatted USB is not recognized in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1163031/gparted-fat32-formatted-usb-is-not-recognized-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some defect in this gparted.  Although Linux is able to mount the resulting filesystem (and the files compare identical to the original), `file -s` shows the following weirdness:

### Before

> /dev/loop0p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", sectors/cluster 8, reserved sectors 3310, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2048, sectors 15114240 (volumes > 32 MB) , FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 14729, serial number 0x9a856b85, unlabeled

### After

> /dev/loop1p1: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 2 : ID=0xb2, start-CHS (0x2f0,0,0), end-CHS (0x0,0,0), startsector 2944401408, 51 sectors; partition 4 : ID=0x65, start-CHS (0x0,0,0), end-CHS (0x163,118,41), startsector 1626349669, 2144852992 sectors

Clearly some part of the Windows 10 Recovery boot path accepts the weirdness - I guess the part where the EFI filesystem driver is used.   Later code must use similar checks to a fully running Windows, and does not accept it.

In the case of a Windows 10 Recovery Drive for UEFI, this could be worked around simply by creating a smaller FAT filesystem and copying the files into it.  (Yes, [really](http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/SLN299044#One) :).

Comment: There is a bug in some versions of the libparted library used by partition tools such as GParted.  See [Bug 759916 - fat(32) resizing generates boot sector(s) with invalid jump instruction and pseudo-random boot code](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759916).  For Windows to recognize FAT32, it needs the initial bytes (at least 3 bytes "eb 58 90") set.  See [Bug 759916 Comment 11](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759916#c11).  A hexeditor can be used to set these three bytes.